# Using aliases in SQL inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I've had a look at a few examples of using joins to get the highest value in a group, but the methods I have tried don't like the use of aliases outside of the inner join.

`SELECT f.year, f.name, f.date_start, f.date_end, f.max_year FROM
(
    SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM date_start) AS year, MAX(DATEDIFF(date_end,date_start)) AS max_year
    FROM mytable GROUP BY year
)
AS x inner join mytable AS f on f.year = x.year and f.max_year = x.max_year;`

So if I have a table:

`Name date_start date_end
John 1950-04-05 1960-07-08
Jack 1950-04-06 1960-12-31
Mark 1954-01-01 1970-01-01
Jane 1954-10-10 1978-10-01`

Then I want it to bring up the entries that have the greatest gap between the two dates, for each year of the start_date:

`Year Name date_start date_end  max_year
1950 Jack 1950-04-06 1960-12-31  3922
1954 Jane 1954-10-10 1978-10-01  8758`

Any suggestions of how to get around this?

Comment: Do you get an error when you run your query or results don't match expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using wrong aliases in your SELECT list, this should be better:

```
SELECT x.year, f.name, f.date_start, f.date_end, x.max_year FROM
(
    SELECT 
      EXTRACT(year FROM date_start) AS year, 
      MAX(DATEDIFF(date_end,date_start)) AS max_year
    FROM mytable GROUP BY year
)  AS x inner join
mytable AS f on  EXTRACT(year FROM f.date_start) = x.year 
AND DATEDIFF(f.date_end, f.date_start) = x.max_year;
```

However, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT name, date_start, date_end
FROM mytable f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable 
  WHERE  
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_start) = EXTRACT(year FROM f.date_start) AND
    DATEDIFF(date_end, date_start) > DATEDIFF(f.date_end, f.date_start)
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bulat, both work very nicely! I now see where I was going wrong with my aliases. I'm quite new to using joins, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, EXTRACT(year FROM date_start) AS year, DATEDIFF(date_end,date_start) AS diff
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY diff DESC
) sq
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year ASC
```

Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d0da/11

Comment: +1 for working solution, but it is mysql hack so I would not recommend to use it.