# Oracle - With a one to many relationship, select distinct rows based on a min value

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, one-to-many, min

This question is the same as [In one to many relationship, return distinct rows based on MIN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551344/in-one-to-many-relationship-return-distinct-rows-based-on-min-value) with the exception that I'd like to see what the answer looks like in other dialects, particularly in Oracle.

Reposting from the original description:

Let's say a patient makes many visits. I want to write a query that returns distinct patient rows based on their earliest visit. For example, consider the following rows.

```
patients
-------------
id    name
1     Bob
2     Jim
3     Mary

visits
-------------
id    patient_id    visit_date    reference_number
1     1             6/29/14       09f3be26
2     1             7/8/14        34c23a9e
3     2             7/10/14       448dd90a
```

What I want to see returned by the query is:

```
id    name    first_visit_date    reference_number
1     Bob     6/29/14             09f3be26
2     Jim     7/10/14             448dd90a
```

In the other question, using postgresql, the best solution seemed to be to use `distinct on`, but that is not available in other dialects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, one uses `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, visit_date as first_visit_date, reference_number
from (select v.id, p.name, v.visit_date, v.reference_number,
             row_number() over (partition by p.id order by v.visit_date desc) as seqnum
      from visits v join
           patients p
           on v.patient_id p.id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```